# Facebook style like system in modx cms (php)

Tags: facebook-like, modx

Trying to build a simple like system in modx (which uses php snippets of code) I just need a button that logged in users can press which adds a 'like' to a resource.

Would it be best to update a custom table or TV? my thoughts are that if it is a template variable i can use getResource to sort by amount of likes.

Any thoughts on the best way to approach this or how to build this would help. My php knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you are going to use it after and if you are storing more data than just a 'like' count. TV's are expensive on resources [even more so if you are going to whip through the entire resource set with getResources] so if you are going to do a lot of processing after the fact I would either look at a custom table ~or~ explore using property sets on your pages [I think it should be pretty easy to write a plugin that will update a page property]

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely go for a custom table.

While you could simply increment a numeric TV to count the amount of likes, you will come to a situation where anyone may be able to keep on liking a resource without limit - while you didn't specify the exact concept, that hardly can be desired. Using a custom table you could throw in a relational alias to the user ID that liked the resource, add a timestamp so you know when it happened, and let your fantasy run wild on additional features that are now open to you.

While not a hard requirement for custom tables, you will probably want to take the time to learn xPDO, which is the database abstraction layer MODX is based on. There's a [great tutorial on the RTFM which walks you through it](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Using+Custom+Database+Tables+in+your+3rd+Party+Components).